# Unity Deserialize JSON Array with inner Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I try to parse json (from a API) to my Object.

The JSON looks like these

```
[
  {
    "bookId": 1,
    "title": "Test Book 1",
    "description": "Test Book 1 Description",
    "coverImageUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    "layout": "FullScreen",
    "categories": [
      1,
      2
    ],
    "tags": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "bookId": 2,
    "title": "Test Book 2",
    "description": "Test Book 2 Description.",
    "coverImageUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    "layout": "FullScreen",
    "categories": [
      1
    ],
    "tags": []
  }
]
```

I use a JSON Helper class:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] getJsonArray<T>(string json)
    {
        string newJson = "{ \"array\": " + json + "}";
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(newJson);
        return wrapper.array;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] array;
    }
}
```

And to Deserialize it, i use:

```
BookDTO[] books;
books = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<BookDTO>(jsonData)
```

And the Books DTO Object looks like the following:
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
namespace API.DTOs
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class BookDTO : DTO
    {
        public int bookId { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string coverImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string layout { get; set; }
        public ICollection<int> categories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<int> tags { get; set; }

        public BookDTO(int bookId, string title, string description, string coverImageUrl, string layout, ICollection<int> categories, ICollection<int> tags)
        {
            this.bookId = bookId;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.coverImageUrl = coverImageUrl;
            this.layout = layout;

            this.categories = categories;
            this.tags = tags;

        }
    }
}
```

And i also tried the following because categories and tags are also arrays:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace API.DTOs
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class BookDTO : DTO
    {
        public int bookId { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string coverImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string layout { get; set; }
        public Categories[] categories { get; set; }
        public Tags[] tags { get; set; }

        public BookDTO(int bookId, string title, string description, string coverImageUrl, string layout, ICollection<int> categories, ICollection<int> tags)
        {
            this.bookId = bookId;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.coverImageUrl = coverImageUrl;
            this.layout = layout;

            string newCategories = "{ \"cat\": " + categories + "}";
            this.categories = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<Categories>(newCategories);
            string newTags = "{ \"tag\": " + tags + "}";
            this.tags = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<Tags>(newTags);

        }
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Categories
    {
        public int[] cat;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Tags
    {
        public int[] tag;
    }
}
```

But always i get a Books array with two books and all values are null.

Comment: Why are you adding "array" to your json text? And if adding it are you capturing it in the DTO base?

Comment: A good tool to use for creating JSON models is https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: As a general rule, unless it's something fairly simple, I would recommend Newtonsoft Json instead of JsonUtility because it's a bit restrictive.

Comment: @Mernayi i adding array, because of this post: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1290561/how-do-i-go-about-deserializing-a-json-array.html
i think unity will map it by parameter names

Comment: @pixlhero you are awesome sir. Works perfectly with Newtonsoft Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Newtonsoft https://www.newtonsoft.com/json
2. List books = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>(jsonData);

And it works - thanks to @pixlhero